# Angular 6 Service Dependency Injection

Tags: angular, service, dependencies, components, code-injection

I do have a *list* in my **ts** file

**component.ts**

```
list: any[];

constructor(
    private listService: ListService
) {}

ngOnInit() {
     this.listService.getListItems()
      .subscribe(
        res => {
        this.list= res;
      },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
  }

passList(){
    this.listService.modifyList(this.list);
}
```

If I do pass my list *as a parameter* in a function to a service, the changes that are made **inside** the service on the list change the list from the *component.ts* file

**ListService.ts**

```
modifyList(list) {
 // operations.changes made on list are propagated in the list from component.ts
}
```

### How?

Comment: if, for example, in the modifyList() function from the service I set list = [ ] , then the list from the component.ts will become empty as well.

Comment: That's normal behaviour, since arrays and objects are passed by reference. If you want to make modifications inside the service that do not affect the component, then you need to clone the list before passing it to the service

Comment: Ok I got it, that could be because the objects inside the `list` array share the same reference as of `modifyList()` parameter `list`. They are two separate arrays, but reference to the objects are same.

Comment: Since in JS, complex types like arrays and objects are passed by reference, doing `list = [ ]` in your `modifyList(list)` function would essentially make the `list` in your component empty as well. It's not a recommended way though as it would make changes to the state of your App you won't be able to reason about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a `BehaviourSubject` in the `ListService` and expose it `asObservable`. And then also create two methods on it. One(`initializeList`) would get the data from API and this will trigger the initialization of the `BehaviourSubject` on this service. The other(`modifyList`) would change the data and would trigger an update on the `BehaviourSubject`.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ListService {

  url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
  private list: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  list$ = this.list.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  initializeList() {
    this.http.get(this.url)
      .subscribe(list => this.list.next(list));
  }

  modifyList(changedList) {
    // Make further modifications to the changedList and then:
    this.users.next(changedUsers);
  }

}
```

In my Component then, I would first call `listService.initializeList` which will initialize the `list` `BehaviorSubject` on the list. And then I would subscribe to the `list$` `observable`.

```
list: any[];

constructor(
  private listService: ListService
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.listService.initializeList();
  this.listService.list$()
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.list = res;
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
}

passList() {
  this.listService.modifyList(this.list);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pass array or object in Function as assignment.It will pass value as reference (i.e both will point to same memory location). If you change in once place will reflect in another end too.

In order to avoid this. Can you take copy of the variable (immutable) and pass it.

**Object:**

this.list = Object.assign({}, this.list);

**Array:**

this.list = this.list.slice();